# Can't use $myvar_.* to mv files starting with $myvar_

Tags: bash, mv

```
week=$(date +%W)
```

I'm trying to move files beginning with `$week` to another folder using `mv`.

So I have a file named:

```
25_myfile.zip
```

And the number at the beginning is a number of a week.  So I want to move it using `mv` from the directory it's currently in to `/mydir/week25/`:

```
mv /mydir/$week\_.* /mydir/week$week;
```

But I get a stat error.

Comment: Your glob is not good: `mv /mydir/${week}_* /mydir/week$week` (no period! it's a glob, not a regex).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you made it! I did not notice that error. You should post an answer explaining this

Comment: @fedorqui: not really… as is, the question should be closed as off-topic because it's only a typographical error. I'm not sure whether the question can be reworded so as to be good for the site.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf something with a title like _Why isn't ${var}.* expanding to filenames starting with $var_ should make.

Comment: @fedorqui: ok! but then _you_ write the answer! (and I've already upvoted your answer, so I won't be able to upvote it further).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

When you say

```
mv /mydir/$week\_.* /mydir/week$week;
#                ^^
```

You are using the syntax `$var\_.*` (or `${var}_.*` if you don't want to have to escape the underscore) you are trying to use globbing, but failing because you use a regular expression syntax.

#### The solution

Use globbing as described in [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.8 Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion). That is

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set (see The Set
>   Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’.
>   If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a
>   pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames
>   matching the pattern (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)).

```
mv /mydir/$week\_* /mydir/week$week;
#                ^
```

or, using `${ }` to define the scope of the name of the variable:

```
mv /mydir/${week}_* /mydir/week$week;
#          ^    ^ ^
```

#### Another approach

You just need an expression like:

```
for file in <matching condition>; do
     mv "$file" /another/dir
done
```

In this case:

```
for file in ${week}_*; do
   mv "$file" /mydir/week"${week}"/
done
```

Because `${week}_*` will expand to those filenames starting with `$week` plus `_`.

See an example:

```
$ touch 23_a
$ touch 23_b
$ touch 23_c
$ touch 24_c
$ d=23
$ echo ${d}*
23_a 23_b 23_c
$ for f in ${d}*; do echo "$f --"; done
23_a --
23_b --
23_c --
```

Comment: I don't understand, why can't I just simply use the `mv` command?

Comment: @Chud37 ah well, you can also say `mv ${week}* /your/dir`.

Comment: @fedoqui ! Thanks again.  It wast he `.*` as opposed to just the `*` that was causing the problem :P

Comment: It should still be `${week}_*` (or, to be more paranoid about non-numeric values or IFS containing numbers, `"${week}_"*`) -- otherwise, `week=1` would match files intended for `week=10`, by virtue of not requiring the underscore to follow the number directly.

Answer (score 1):

Below is another alternative using `find`

```
week=25 && find /mydir -type f -not -path "/mydir/week*" \
-name "$week*zip" -exec mv {} "/mydir/week$week" \;
```